# Long line cannot be drawn

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-bitmap, android-graphics

I wrote a custom view, called `DottedLine` that basically draws a vertical line, with a certain height.

The class overrides `onDraw` with something like:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, size, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() - getHeight() % (size + gap), paint);
    }
```

No need to understand in the details the expressions passed as parameters of the `drawLine` method. It is enough to know that the **height can be pretty big** (depending on the device, probably on the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` limit), because the view can be part of a scrollable layout.

The problem is that when is long enough I get a warning and cannot render the line.

`W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (42x5480, max=4096x4096)`

I am thinking about splitting the line in pieces, but this is gonna have a big impact on the current implementation.

Do you have any idea about how this problem could be addressed?